# How to create a cron job on windows to call a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, windows, cron, nncron

I am trying to create a cron job on Windows to call a MySQL stored procedure.  The destination of this job is a unix box however I am currently in a Windows 7 environment.  I have found a Windows tool that uses the exact same syntax as unix' cron, which can be found at http://www.nncron.ru/ - I am using the nnCron LITE version.  I can make this tool do simple things such as open an application etc however have hit a wall trying to call an SP.

The version on MySQL is 5.07 therefore MySQL events are not an option.  Hopefully someone can think of another option, or has used nnCron, or has dome this using a different tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `mysql` executable on your Windows machine, you should be able to set up a scheduled task to invoke like this:

```
c:\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe --user=cron --password=secret --execute="call stored_procedure_name()"
```

You do not need any third party software (nnCron or similar). Windows has a built in task scheduler which will happily run this task for you.

Comment: thank you for your reply however the destination of the solution is a linux machine.  This is why I am trying to use nnCron on windows to get the syntax that will work on the linux box.  Sorry if my question was not clear. The linux box is not available to my at the moment.  Do you think the tack I am taking is possible?  I thought since nnCron uses the same syntax as what would be used on a linux cron job it should be achievable?